# Is Rey using meditation during a lightsaber duel with Kylo?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force

As far as I know, Force meditation should be performed in a calm fashion. As [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Meditation) states:

> By meditating, Force-sensitives could reach a deeper state of relaxation, making them easier to connect with the Force with a clear mind.

Even powerful Jedi master Qui-Gon Jinn is meditating during a "stand-off" period while lasers separates them.

Why is Rey meditating in the middle of a lightsaber duel? And why is Kylo waiting patiently for her to gather strength, instead of pulling his lightsaber back and attacking her repeatedly from other side while she meditates? That whole scene was so surreal for me... Rey was like "Oh! The Force!" and she kind of doze off for a while, and Kylo is just looking at her in anger.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure precisely which scene you're referring to, but the novelization only describes one time in their duel which could be considered "meditative"; in that instant, which is really not that long, Ren is holding off because he's just offered (earnestly) to teach her the ways of the Dark Side:

> You need a teacher." He was beseeching and insistent all at once. "I can show you the ways of the Force!"
>
> Slowly she shook her head. "The Force?" That was what this was about? Instead of moving to defend herself, Rey closed her eyes. Ren hesitated, confused by her actions. A long moment passed, in which Ren sensed a change in the air, a change in *her*. Then she opened her eyes and attacked, viciously
>
> <sup>*The Force Awakens* Chapter XVIII</sup>

Killing her immediately would be [rather rude](https://youtu.be/nDwQJ64UpFQ) after that.

This also holds in the film as well, mind. Re-watching the scene, it's clear that Rey is the one struggling, and Ren is easing up on her (slightly); as before, he's just offered to teach her and really wants to give her a chance to answer:

> She seems to be, impossibly, STRONGER THAN HE IS for half a dozen blows -- until he FINDS HIS STRENGTH and FIGHTS BACK -- MOVING FORWARD and PUSHING REY BACK, into the forest. Suddenly a COLOSSAL CHUNK OF THE FOREST RIGHT BEHIND REY DROPS AWAY! Rey is suddenly fighting on the EDGE OF A MASSIVE, BRAND NEW CLIFF!
>
> **Kylo Ren:** You need a teacher! I can show you the ways of the Force!
>
> <sup>*The Force Awakens* (2015)</sup>

Comment: Yea, that scene. In the movie, they have their lightsaber locked in a violent way, so it looks like Kylo Ren was still trying very hard to kill her, but instead of using the situation, he let her meditate (even if just for a few long seconds). But your answer makes sense, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: @Sebustyan I just re-watched the scene; on the contrary, it looks to me like Rey is trying very hard not to be killed, and Ren is actually easing up on her a bit

Comment: Force Users have a compelling need to have an apprentice, this leads to similar behaviour. Darth Tyranus, holding advantage against Obi Wan and Anakin Skywalker, tried to convince them to join him. Darth Maul, powerful Sith Lord, withheld himself against Ezra Bridger, attempting to recruit him. Darth Vader, holding an advantage in combat, paused to have a conversation with Luke Skywalker. Emperor Palpatine, who's foresight failed him, toyed with Luke Skywalker.  It would seem that along with awesome force powers, a force user has a burning need to have an apprentice!

Comment: "*“‘The Force’?” she repeated, sounding confused and exasperated all at once. She closed her eyes for a moment, then lunged at Ren again, more furious than before. And for once, Kylo Ren dueled an opponent who had more anger than he. Or maybe what fueled her wasn’t anger. Maybe it was an emotion he didn’t recognize anymore. Whatever it was, it took him down.*" - Junior novelisation

Comment: I don't think Kylo Ren really wanted to kill her, instead he was fighting to both defend himself and to disarm her at the same time. When he saw that she was about to go over the cliff, he paused and offered her the chance to stand down and join him.